# How to setup default arguments for class methods as class variables?

Tags: python, class, keyword-argument

I would like to have sensible default arguments for the class methods as class variables. These variables should be passed to class methods as they are called unless the user wants to override them. I came up with the solution below but I am not sure if this is makes sense. It does what I want it to do but I am curious to learn if there is a better or more Pythonic way to do this.

```py
from copy import deepcopy


class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = {'meow': {'volume': 10.2,
                                    'pitch': 'E'},
                           'sleep': {'duration': 100,
                                     'snore': True,
                                     'dream': True}}

    def meow(self, **kwargs):
        params = self._set_parameters('meow', kwargs)
        print('Meowing at {volume} dB in {pitch}'.format(**params))

    def sleep(self, **kwargs):
        params = self._set_parameters('sleep', kwargs)
        print('Sleeping for {duration} hours...\n'
              'Snore: {snore}\nDream: {dream}'.format(**params))

    def _set_parameters(self, action, kwargs):
        params = deepcopy(self.parameters[action])
        for key in kwargs:
            if key in params:
                params[key] = kwargs[key]
        return params
```

Here when a class method is called without any parameters if uses the default values.

```py
Sleepycat = Cat()
Sleepycat.sleep()

>>> Sleeping for 100 hours...
    Snore: True
    Dream: True
```

The user can also give a keyword argument to override defaults:

```py
Loudcat = Cat()
Loudcat.meow(volume=100)

>>> Meowing at 100 dB in E
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
         self.sleep_duration = 100
         self.sleep_snore = True
         self.sleep_dream = True

    def sleep(self, 
              duration=100, 
              snore=True, 
              dream=True):
        self.sleep_duration = duration
        self.sleep_snore = snore
        self.sleep_dream = dream

        print('Sleeping for {0} hours...\n'
              'Snore: {1}\nDream: {2}'.format(
                self.sleep_duration, self.sleep_snore, self.sleep_dream))
```

Comment: That's what I was initially going for but I think this has more redundant code. You need to declare all the default arguments twice and when you have a lot of class methods and keyword arguments this becomes a little messy.